# Comparing arithmetic complexity of FFT radix-2 and convolution

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, convolution

Let's assume we have a discrete linear time invariant system and we have a real signal $x[n]$ with length N=50 as input for the system.

The impulse response $h[n]$ of the system is considered to be also a real signal with length M=10.

We want to calculate the output signal $y[n]$.

There are two ways we can do this: We can either convolute the signals $x[n]$,$h[n]$ in the time domain or use FFT radix-2 and work on the frequency domain.

I want to **compare the arithmetic complexity of these two methods in number of real multiplications**.I know that the arithmetic complexity of convolution is $N \cdot M$ since $N \cdot M$ real multiplications are required in order to calculate $y[n]$. However, I am bit confused with FFT-radix 2.

I know that it requires $μ(Ν) = \frac{N}{2}\log _{2}N$ complex multiplications. Every complex multiplication is equivelant to 4 real multiplications. So how many real multiplications are required to calculate $y[n]$? Do I have to calculate first both $X[k]$ and $H[k]$ by using $\frac{50}{2}\log _{2}50 + \frac{10}{2}\log _{2}10 $ real multiplications? And if so, how do I go on?

Comment: If you have an input signal that's substantially longer then the filter, the best way to go is often "overlap add", i.e. you break it down into a set of smaller FFTs instead one large one. In your example, this won't make much of a difference since both signal and impulse response are "short".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the input signal $x[n]$ has a legth of $N=50$ samples, and the filter $h[n]$ has a length of $M=10$ samples, then the output $y[n]$ (by linear conv) will have a length of $L = N+M-1=59$ samples.

If you use time-domain convolution, then the number of real MACS can be seen to be  $N \cdot M = 50 \times 10 = 500$.

If you want to use radix-2 FFT to implement the linear convolution result, then you should select a length of $R = 64$ for FFTs. And you will: 1- convert $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ into $X[k]$ and $H[k]$ by two $R$-point FFTS, 2- multiply the results to get $Y[k] = X[k]H[k]$, and 3- apply inverse FFT of $R$-point on $Y[k]$ to get the output $y[n]$.

Each $R$-point FFT (and IFFT) requires about $\frac{1}{2} R  \cdot \log_2(R)$ complex MACs. One complex MAC is 4 real MACs, therefore this is equivalent to $ 2 ~R ~ \log_2(R) = 128 \log_2(64) = 128 \times 6 = 768 $ real MACs. And the total of two FFTs and one inverse FFT requires about $3 \times 768 = 2304$ real MACs. The intermediate multiplication also requires $4 \times R = 256$ real MACs and hence FFT based implementation requires a total of $2560$ real MACs.

So in this case, time-domain convolution is more efficient than an FFT based implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!It is really helpful!However,If the length **$R$** of FFTs is not specified and I want to make a comparison about the complexity of these two methods (knowing only the lengths of $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ as in it is in this example) which is the appropriate value for the FFT length **$R$** ? I mean if I want to make a general comparison between these two methods by knowing only the lengths of input signal and impulse response signal which is a correct estimation for the value of **$R$**?Cause in this case we got that **$R=64$** in order to decide which method is more efficient

Comment: For radix-2 FFT the best R that yields minimum number of MACs is R = 64. For non radix-2 FFT then the minimum R that yields the output $y[n]$ without aliasing is $R = 59$. However the formula $0.5 R \log_2(R)$ is valid for radix-2 FFT complexity computation. Non radix-2 FFT compexity is larger than radix-2 case.

Comment: So if I get it right, in my case, I can assume that **$R=64$** and make the calculations as u did, right?

Comment: @MJ13 yes that's right...

Comment: Ok...Just one thing I don't get...Doesn't the length **$R$** of the FFTs have to be smaller or equal to the length of the sequences? I mean input signal sequence $x[n]$ has length **$N=50$**. How can we apply a DFT of $R$ samples? What am I missing?

Comment: No. FFT length must be equal or greater than sequence length $y[n]$ if you want to get unaliased (exact) results. Computing R=64 point FFT of N=50 and M=10 point sequences is done by **zero-padding** (at the end) of the sequences by enlarging them to R=64 point sequences.

Comment: Oh ok now I get it...So what about if my input signal has a length of $N=100$ ? Do I have to assume then that $R=128$ or $R=256$ if my input is $N=200$ for instance?

Comment: let $v = \log_2(N)$ then $ R = 2^{r+1}$

Comment: you may accept the answer if that answered your question.

Comment: Just one final question: Are you sure that the number of total real MCAs for the convolution is almost equal to $(N+M-1)\cdot M$ and not $N \cdot M$ ?

Comment: Yes the **exact** count of MACs  is $$ M \cdot N$$ after adding the intermediate full overlaps and transient partial overlap counts. However note that in the answer I have referred to $L \cdot M$ as the approx (overstated) count. L being the **output** signal length.

Comment: Knowing that the input is zero-padded and real-valued, you can skip some multiplications in the first FFT stage. But in this case direct convolution probably remains faster still. If the filter is constant, you can precompute its FFT and that would make the FFT approach faster.

Comment: @jpa Oh thanks ! I just forgot to multiply the FFT MAC count by 3, let me correct it and you remake your comment then.

Comment: Is any time saved by using the conjugate symmetry of the FFTs of real-valued signals to _deduce_ the value of  $X[N-k]Y[N-k] = X[k]^*Y[k]^* = (X[k]Y[k])^*$ from the computed value of $X[k]Y[k]$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I didn't think that this question was asking for a through discussion of every possible FFT trick to reduce the complexity, but instead just looking for a general outline. And of course the conjugate symmetry can be utilized to reduce the computation as much as possible...

Comment: @Fat32 So, the exact number of MACs for the calculation of $y[n]$ in my example, using the convolution method, is $N \cdot M = 500$ , right?

Comment: @MJ13 yes the exact count of real MACs in time domain implementation is M*N = 500. You can still reduce this number if the filter is linear phase. But no, ask another question for that.

Comment: @Fat32 Just one more little clarification. You said that the length **$R$** we use for the FFT-2 radix should be greater or equal to the length of $y[n]$ sequence. Right? So here **$R$** it has to be greater or equal to $59$. Why should the value $64$ be a better option? It leads to more MCAs than $59$. And why does the $R$ cannot be $50$ which is bigger than both signal lengths?

Comment: @MJ13 min R = 64 because it's **radix-2**... :-)  When R = 59 you cannot use radix-2 and it will be less efficient = more MACs. And R should be greater than the length of y[n] not the intermediate signal lengths

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks for your extensive explanations! Made it more clear!